# How to create TreeMap of ArrayList in Groovy

Tags: arraylist, groovy, treemap

I've created an ArrayList by looping over an array of values, which creates an array in the "common" key/value structure.

```
def timeWithIdentifier = []
for (i = 0; i <= time.size()-1; i++) {
     timeWithIdentifier [i] = i + ":'" + time[i] + "'";
}
```

The array looks like the following:
`timeWithIdentifier = [0:'1423734900000', 1:'1423735200000', 2:'1423735500000', 3:'1423735800000', 4:'1423736100000', 5:'1423736400000', 6:'1423736700000', 7:'1423737000000', 8:'1423737300000', 9:'1423737600000', 10:'1423737900000', 11:'1423738200000', 12:'1423738500000', 13:'1423738800000', 14:'1423739100000', 15:'1423739400000', 16:'1423739700000', 17:'1423740000000', 18:'1423740300000', 19:'1423740600000', 20:'1423740900000', 21:'1423741200000', 22:'1423741500000', 23:'1423741800000', 24:'1423742100000', 25:'1423742400000']`

Asking for the class of this via `timeWithIdentifier.getClass()` I get the following result `java.util.ArrayList`.

Now I want to put the above key/value combination in a new TreeMap by using the following: `treeMapTime = new TreeMap<Integer, Long>(timeWithIdentifier )`

Unfortunately I get the following error

> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.TreeMap(java.util.ArrayList)

What am I missing about it?

Comment: I think you expect something different in place of `timeWithIdentifier`. The type of this variable is `ArrayList<String>`, it's not key-value structure, but simple zero-indexed list that is recommended for random access like structure. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

Here's how it should be done:

```
def time = (1..10)
def timeWithIdentifier = [:]
for (i = 0; i <= time.size()-1; i++) {
     timeWithIdentifier[i] = time[i]
}

new TreeMap(timeWithIdentifier)
```

**Explanation:**

As can be seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) `TreeMap` doesn't take an `ArrayList` as constructor argument - `Map` should be passed.

When processing items with for loop you're not creating instances of `Maps` but strings. Change `timeWithIdentifier` to an instance of `Map` an add item under `i` key. Then pass whole `timeWithIdentifier` as an argument `TreeMap` constructor. It can be even easier:

```
def time = (1..10)
def timeWithIdentifier = [:] as TreeMap
for (i = 0; i <= time.size()-1; i++) {
     timeWithIdentifier[i] = time[i]
}
```

Comment: Hey Opal, This way exactly what I've needed. Thank you very much :-) Just one last question (due to a mistake in my question (actually the order of key/value should be the other way round)): How would it look, if **time** should be the key and the **stepNumber** the value? Actually I want to get the time by calling `firstKey()` and `lastKey()...`

Comment: As far as I understood it would be `timeWithIdentifier[time] = i`. If it works, please accept and upvote.

Comment: `timeWithIdentifier[time[i]] = i` did the trick. Using `timeWithIdentifier[time] = i` results in  **java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable**
Anyway...thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Ah sure. `time` was defined differently ;) Thanks!